# How do I make an HTTP POST from a non-browser device?

Tags: c, json, post, http-headers, ansi-c

I'm making an http post request from a non-browser device (POS, point of sale), is programmed in C.

Doing an http GET request work perfectly, I receive the answer from the server. I just connect with the Host, build the msg, for example:

```
strcpy(msjEnv, "GET /app/appinfo/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
               "Host: 185.12.25.138\n"
               "User-Agent: 3C377521\n"
               "\n"
               "\0");
```

and I send `msjEnv`, to get, as I said, the answer (JSON) that I need from the server.

Now, with the http POST request, the server, someway doesn't receive the body of the build msg, for example:

```
strcpy(msjEnv, "POST /services/s/Core/login HTTP/1.1\r\n"
               "Host: 185.12.25.138:7004\r\n"
               "auth: asdasd\r\n"
               "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
               "\r\n"
               "disp=101010&usr=987676&pass=123456&app=POS\0");
```

When I see the console(trace) of the server, I can see that the POS connect with the server but the BODY of the msg (`disp=101010&usr=896464&pass=9514&app=WPOS`) is all null.

I've done a test with Postman (An excelent app fron chrome app store to test the API's) and I receive the correct response.

I'm thinking I need something extra in the POST header because, as an non-browser device, maybe I have not some automatic configuration for comunication as, i think that has, the browser. Have any idea?

Comment: You don't need to put `\0` at the end of a string literal, C does that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Content-Length header to your request.